# weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl class not found

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, jar, weblogic

I'm coding a little servlet using `weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl`. My IDE(`JDeveloper`) doesn't say something wrong. But after launching app, I'm catching `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl`. Should I add new `jar` files to lib directory? This is what `lib` contains:

[image]

Comment: You should add Middleware\wlserver_10.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar...

Comment: Probably the WS client was created by Weblogic's clientgen?

Comment: I don't know. I created new web service project using JDeveloper. It works, but then I add all generated code into servlet project.

Comment: So you should deploy it in a Weblogic Server. What container are you using?

Comment: Well you cannot deploy a Weblogic's specific client classes into Jboss

Comment: You can change your IDE; I'd suggest Eclipse and this tutorial: http://docs.jboss.org/tools/nightly/trunk/en/ws_soap_reference/html/client.html

Comment: This type of problem is solved using Maven. Why don't you use it for dependency management in 2020?

Answer (score 0):

If you use weblogic 12.x then the jar that contains `weblogic.wsee.jaxrpc.ServiceImpl` is located in

```
{WL_INSTALL_FOLDER}/wlserver/modules/clients/com.oracle.webservices.wls.jaxws-wlswss-client.jar
```

or

```
wls.jaxrpc-client
```

depending on which one you use.

If you add that to your lib, it should work.